# jHipster Registry on AWS Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, jhipster, jhipster-registry

I've been looking for a way to deploy jhipster microservices to AWS. It seems like jhipster registry provides an easy way to monitor jhipster microservices but I am yet to find a way to deploy jhipster registry to AWS. Cloning jhipster-registry GitHub repo and running `jhipster aws` returns "Error: Sorry deployment for this database is not possible".

Alternatively, creating a Docker image with `mvn compile jib:buildTar` and using generated *target/jib-image.tar* as an AWS Beanstalk app version also fails because it's missing Dockerfile.

What's a good way to deploy jhipster registry to AWS Beanstalk and subsequently use it for monitoring other jhipster microservices deployed to AWS Beanstalk?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error I ended up doing something like this:

1. Clone https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry
2. Build a Docker container locally with `./mvnw package -Pprod verify jib:dockerBuild`
3. Create an ECR registry in AWS console or using AWS CLI as follows: `aws --profile [AWS_PROFILE] ecr create-repository --repository-name [ECR_REGISTRY_NAME]`
4. Assuming that v6.3.0 was cloned in step 1, tag the local Docker as follows: `image docker tag [IMAGE_ID] [AWS_ACCOUNT].dkr.ecr.[AWS_REGION].amazonaws.com/[ECR_REGISTRY_NAME]:jhipster-registry-6.3.0`
5. Authenticate to ECR as follows: `eval $(aws --profile [AWS_PROFILE] ecr get-login --no-include-email --region [AWS_REGION])`
6. Push the local Docker image to ECR as follows: `docker push [AWS_ACCOUNT].dkr.ecr.[AWS_REGION].amazonaws.com/[ECR_REGISTRY_NAME]:jhipster-registry-6.3.0`
7. Set up [Elastic Beanstalk (EB) CLI](https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup)
8. Initialize local EB project as follows: `eb init --profile [AWS_PROFILE]`
9. Create Dockerrun.aws.json with the following content:

```js
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Image": {
    "Name": "[AWS_ACCOUNT].dkr.ecr.[AWS_REGION].amazonaws.com/[ECR_REGISTRY_NAME]:jhipster-registry-6.3.0",
    "Update": "true"
  },
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": 8761
    }
  ]
}
```

10. Run jhipster-locally as follows: `eb local run --port 8761`
11. Verify that you can access jhipster-registry locally as follows: `eb local open`
12. Create a new EB environment running the Docker image from the ECR as follows: `eb create [EB_ENV_NAME] --instance-types t2.medium --keyname [EC2_KEY_PAIR_NAME] \ --vpc.id [VPC_ID] --vpc.ec2subnets [EC2_SUBNETS] --vpc.publicip --vpc.elbpublic --vpc.securitygroups [CUSTOM_ELB_SG]`
13. Access remote jhipster-registry as follows: `eb open`